# C++ Make Lower Function

Tags: c++, string, tolower

I wrote a simple function in c++ to turn a string in to all lower case letters using chars and iterating through each char in the string. Can someone please explain why when I run this program in the console window, I get an output in addition to my original input if the function never references cout.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
string makelower(string text)
{
    int iter = 0;
    char cha;
    string newtext;
    while (iter < text.length())
    {
        cha = text[iter];
        cha = tolower(cha);
        newtext+=cha;
        iter++;
    }
    return(newtext);
}

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    a = makelower(a);
    cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: why not `makelower(a)` ?

Comment: sorry @macfij that's what I meant.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, could you please explain.

Comment: @cybermonkey could you elaborate on why please?

Comment: @OrrenRavid I went by what Oliver said as I do not have access to my laptop at the moment (it's in its bag and I can't be bothered to boot it up, my desktop doesn't have VS installed). See my answer, I've answered in far more detail than echen's simple answer.

Comment: @OrrenRavid I'm confused on the edit you just made to your question. Please clarify the `hello` variable.

Comment: @cybermonkey I apologize, my initial string was called hello instead of a. I changed it to avoid confusion. I guess it caused more confusion than it avoided because I forgot to change all instances of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

putchar writes a character out to stdout
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/

Comment: Unsure whether this answers the question. At least, it doesn't *directly* answer it. Please expand your answer.

Comment: @cybermonkey how does it not answer the question? "Can someone please explain why when I run this program in the console window, I get an output..."

Comment: @MarkRansom The answer should still be explained in better detail. I flagged it for moderator attention since I'm confused here.

Comment: @cybermonkey: It's certainly a direct and concise answer to the question. And what should a moderator do with your flag but dismiss it as inappropriate?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code.  Perhaps the most
significant one is that you haven't defined what you mean by converting
to lower case; it's not always as obvious as it seems.  However:

- To iterate over the characters in a string, you use iterators, and you
  test for the end; in C++11, you can use a range based loop.
- The argument to the single argument form of `tolower` must have a value
  between 0 and `UCHAR_MAX`; if you have a `char`, this is normally
  achieved by converting it to `unsigned char`.
- If you want to return a string, then you should append the characters to
  it as you convert them; alternatively, you can do the changes in place
  by having `makelower` take a non-const reference.  I'd recommend the
  former.

Taking all of this into consideration:

```
std::string
makeLower( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results;
    for ( unsigned char ch : text ) {
        results += std::tolower( ch );
    }
    return results;
}
```

To use this function, you call it with a string, and either initialize
another string with its results, or assign it to a string.  Or just use
it in an expression where you need a string.

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, a ) && !line.empty() ) {
    std::cout << makeLower( a ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `putchar` function *puts* outputs the assigned character to `stdout`. Additional information on this can be [found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/), and you should *instead* simply `tolower` the `char`:

```
string makelower(string text)
{
    int iter = 0;
    char cha;
    while (text[iter])
    {
        tolower(text[iter]);
        iter++;
    }
return(text);
}
```

Making your *full* program like this (I've also made the code more efficient):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

string makelower(string text)
{
    int iter = 0;
    while (text[iter])
    {
        tolower(text[iter]);
        iter++;
    }
    return(text);
}

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    a = makelower(a);
    cin >> a;
}
```

An `#include <string>` was missing which stopped the code from compiling when I tested it properly, so I added it in. Remove it if you already have it.